# Unicode message decode via MySQL

Tags: mysql, decoding

```
<?php
function unicodeMessageEncode($message){
    return '@U' . strtoupper(bin2hex(mb_convert_encoding($message, 'UTF-16','UTF-8')));
}

function unicodeMessageDecode($message) {
    $message = substr($message, 2);
    $_message = hex2bin($message);
    $message = mb_convert_encoding($_message, 'UTF-8', 'UTF-16');
    return $message;
}

$message = "Testing Message ";
$encode_message = unicodeMessageEncode($message);
$decode_message = unicodeMessageDecode($encode_message);

echo $message;
echo "\n";
echo $encode_message;
echo "\n";
echo $decode_message;
echo "\n";

?>
```

I m using the above PHP code to encode and decode Unicode message, Could any know how can I decode Unicode message via MySQL query? (I don't want to run a loop of MySQL result).

For Example: Select id,somefunction(message) from table;

Comment: In your place I wouldn't hassle with encoding but store emojis **as is**

Comment: https://phpize.online/?phpses=16f0d589dbcfdeb529be8048194696b9

Comment: I can not change the existing data, much appreciate it if anyone gives a solution with respect to the current data.